# python looping over n consecutive items in a list

Tags: python

I need to iterate over n consecutive elements in a list.
For example:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I need to go over:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

or:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
```

Is there zip function to do that?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but try this:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

n = 3

[data[i:i+n] for i in range(len(data) - n + 1)]

# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Or:

```
f = lambda data, n: [data[i:i+n] for i in range(len(data) - n + 1)]

for x, y, z in f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3):
    print x, y, z
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are always doing this for a list or another sequence and it does not need to work with arbitrary iterables:

```
def group(seq, n):
    return (seq[i:i+n] for i in range(len(seq)-n+1))
```

Examples:

```
>>> list(group([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 2))
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
>>> list(group([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3))
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
```

If you need to do this for any arbitrary iterable (that may not support `len()` or slicing), you can adapt the [pairwise recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def group(iterable, n):
    "group(s, 3) -> (s0, s1, s2), (s1, s2, s3), (s2, s3, s4), ..."
    itrs = tee(iterable, n)
    for i in range(1, n):
        for itr in itrs[i:]:
            next(itr, None)
    return izip(*itrs)

>>> list(group(iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]), 2))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
>>> list(group(iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]), 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Specific answer:

```
>>> zip(data,data[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
```

General answer:

```
>>> def consecutives(data,per_set):
...   return zip(*[data[n:] for n in range(per_set)])
...
>>> consecutives(range(1,8),2)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]
>>> consecutives(range(1,8),3)
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
>>> consecutives(range(1,8),4)
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to iterate over the sub-lists or a flat list:

```
from itertools import chain
for x in chain(*[ a[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(a)-n+1) ]):
    print x
```

Or:

```
for x in [ a[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(a)-n+1) ]:
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way, but still useful:

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> map(None,data[:-1],data[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)]

>>> map(None,data[:-2],data[1:-1],data[2:])
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: I realize now zip(*args) and map(None,*args) do the same thing, at least in this context.

Answer (score -4):

This is a fairly simple task to program yourself. I dont think there is a pre-canned function to do this.

```
def func(arr,n):
    i = 0
    while i+n < len(arr):
       for range(i,i+n):
          .... make stuff here....
       i = i + 1
```

Comment: So far I have this I am looking for a one liner:
def loopover(listk,n):
    l1=[];s=0
    while(len(listk)):
        for i in range(0,len(listk)):
            l1.append(listk[s:n]);
            s=s+1;  n=n+1;